# Trying to add the deposits interest amount back to the interest label

Tags: java, banking

So i have been trying to create a bank account GUI for this project that i am doing.
The problem i have is when trying to have a deposit TextField allows people to enter in a amount to add to the balance. Once this is done i want to also have what has been deposited into another label which displays the interest on top of that amount that was entered.

This is what i have created so far

```
double CredAccInterest = 1;
double CurrAccInterest = 0.1;
double DepAccInterest = 3;
double SavAccInterest = 0.5;

double Deposit = Integer.parseInt(txtDeposit.getText());
double Balance = Integer.parseInt(lblSetBalance.getText());
double NewBalance = Balance + Deposit;
String NewBalWithDeposit = String.valueOf(NewBalance);
lblSetBalance.setText(NewBalWithDeposit);  

Object AccountType = cbAccounts.getSelectedItem();

String AccType = AccountType.toString();

if("Credit Account".equals(AccType))
     {
       String CurrentInterest = lblSetBalanceWithInterest.getText();
       double CurrentInterestInt = Integer.parseInt(CurrentInterest);
       double InterestAmount = Deposit * CredAccInterest;
       double NewInterestAmount = InterestAmount + CurrentInterestInt;
       String NewInterest = String.valueOf(NewInterestAmount);
       lblSetBalanceWithInterest.setText(NewInterest);
     }
```

Comment: As a side note, please read up on camelCase: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase. It makes your code MUCH easier to read

Comment: If you are referring to my layout i was just trying to get this code to work

Comment: Camel Case is a way of writing names in program code starting with small case (except of class name), and all first letter of a words should be written as a capital letter. Example: `String currentinterest;` should be `String currentIntrest;` or `int veryBigNameToShowHowItWorksButRememberToKeepYourNamesLengthToTheMinimum = 1;`